# Get the number of physical cores with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I need to get the amount of physical CPU cores with Python.

My CPU has 4 cores and 8 threads. I know a couple of functions like `os.cpu_count` and `multiprocessing.cpu_count`, but they return 8 which is the amount of threads, not cores. How can I get the amount of cores, not threads? Is there any function in Python for that?